# Como transformar uma String java em um Objeto Array Java?

Tags: java, array, jsp

Em uma página .jsp, tenho o seguinte código:

```
String[] arrayRegioes = request.getParameterValues("numRegiaoUsuario");//objeto
```

Quando imprimo o `arrayRegioes`, o valor mostrado é:

> [Ljava.lang.String;@5a879b45

**Agora, preciso transformar uma string que foi feita na mão:**

```
[55826586566, 54555555454, 994139792]
```

**Em um objeto `array`, como o formato daquele informado acima.**

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayRegioes))` vai imprimir o array corretamente (isto é, vai imprimir a lista de elementos em vez de `[Ljava.lang.String;@5a879b45`).

Comment: Array de Int ou String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia tentar usar algo do tipo. 
PS: Não testei, é apenas algo que lembro da época de faculdade.

```
String[] array = values.split(",");
```

Caso possa existir uma string com valores nulos, você deve usar um segundo parâmetro, segue exemplo.

```
String[] array = values.split("\\|", -1);
```

Comment: No caso do OP ele provavelmente vai ter que remover o primeiro e último caracteres também (`[`, `]`), isso pode ser feito com `substring` ou `replace`.

Comment: Para criar o array, tenho que remover os colchetes da string ?

Comment: Ocorreu o erro: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"